# How do I pass array of key,value pairs to golang slice of struct through json

Tags: json, api, go, hyperledger

I am writing a simple post api request. I am able to parse the JSON into golang structs upto the peername json object. I do not know the correct syntax to populate a golang slice of a struct by passing values through the JSON body of the api.

I am trying to parse JSON body sent through an api. This is the sample body request -

```
{  
   "type":"string",
   "name":"string",
   "organization":{  
      "orgID":"1",
      "orgName":"string",
      "peer":{  
         "peerID":"1",
         "peerName":"string"
      },
      "attributes":[
    ["slide0001.html", "Looking Ahead"],
    ["slide0008.html", "Forecast"],
    ["slide0021.html", "Summary"]
]
    }
} "peerName":"string"
          },
          "attributes":["name":"string":"value":true]
        }
    }
```

And this is my sample golang structs.

```
//Identity ...
type Identity struct {
    Type         string        `json:"type,omitempty"`
    Name         string        `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Organization *Organization `json:"organization,omitempty"`
}

//Organization ....
type Organization struct {
    OrgID      string      `json:"orgID,omitempty"`
    OrgName    string      `json:"orgName,omitempty"`
    Peer       *Peer       `json:"peer,omitempty"`
    Attributes *Attributes `json:"attributes"`
}

//Peer ...
type Peer struct {
    PeerID   string `json:"peerID,omitempty"`
    PeerName string `json:"peerName,omitempty"`
}

//Attributes ...
type Attributes []struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Value bool   `json:"value"`
}
```

Comment: That's not valid json. Have you verified that you're starting with the correct data?

Comment: I am aware its not, I am looking for the valid json. I am unaware of the proper syntax for slice of structs.

Comment: The Attributes field is a slice.  The corresponding JSON value is an object.  Either change the JSON to include a JSON array or change the Go type to remove the slice. It's unclear which one you want.

Comment: Thanks ThunderCat. I changed the JSON. Also edited the question. Still need help.

Comment: The JSON is invalid.   When looking past the errors in the JSON, the JSON does not match the Go types.  It's unclear if your goal is to match the Go types to the JSON or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the correct syntax. We have to pass an array of structs through JSON.

```
{  
   "type":"string",
   "name":"string",
   "organization":
   {  
      "orgID":"1",
      "orgName":"string",
      "peer":
      {  
         "peerID":"1",
         "peerName":"string"
      },
      "attributes":
      [
        {"slide0001.html": "Looking Ahead"},
        {"slide0008.html": "Forecast"},
        {"slide0021.html": "Summary"}
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do whatever you want in a `UnmarshalJSON` Function.

i made an example in playground. https://play.golang.org/p/WY6OCR8K3Co

you can get output:  `{A:[{Name:slide0001.html Value:Looking Ahead} {Name:slide0008.html Value:Forecast} {Name:slide0021.html Value:Summary}]}`

```golang
var (
    jso = []byte(`
    {  
        "attributes":
        [
            {"slide0001.html": "Looking Ahead"},
            {"slide0008.html": "Forecast"},
            {"slide0021.html": "Summary"}
        ]
     }`)
)

type B struct {
    A As `json:"attributes"`
}

type As []A

type A struct {
    Name  string
    Value string
}

func (as *As) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var attr []interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &attr); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(attr) > 0 {
        newAs := make([]A, len(attr))
        // i := 0
        for i, val := range attr {
            if kv, ok := val.(map[string]interface{}); ok && len(kv) > 0 {
                for k, v := range kv {
                    a := A{
                        Name:  k,
                        Value: v.(string),
                    }
                    newAs[i] = a
                    i++
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        *as = newAs
    }
    return nil
}
```